# how do I persist changes made to an array inside an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I've got an array of history items that is located inside of a product object:

```
 class Product
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Paranoia
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    ...
    embeds_many :modification_histories
```

My biz rule is that only the last 120 histories are saved. So when a new one gets added, I sort the old ones and pop the array:

```
if self.modification_histories.size >= 120
   self.modification_histories.sort! { |x,y| y.date <=> x.date  }
  while self.modification_histories.size >= 120
     self.modification_histories.pop
  end
end
```

This seems to be working fine, I've put a breakpoint after the call to that method and the history array is the right size. But when I save the object (`self.save!`) then reload it, the history array hasn't been altered. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

`gem "mongoid", "~> 2.4"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: copy the array into another array. Instead of:

`self.modification_histories.sort! { |x,y| y.date <=> x.date  }`

do

```
arr = self.modification_histories.sort { |x,y| y.date <=> x.date  }
while arr.size >= 120
    arr.pop
end
self.modification_histories = arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also compress it down to a single line:

```
self.update_attribute(:modification_histories, self.modification_histories.sort{ |x,y| y.date <=> x.date }[0...120])
```